# Show only first value if equals and group by id in sqlite db 3?

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by

I have payment table and i want to see all payments group by id and years.

payment table

```
ID                 CustomerId    Year
bc7e8ab29          1             2013
35bf3b856          1             2014
667fa9a36          2             2011
51a1e0913          2             2012
```

I want to get table like this:

```
   CustomerId    YEAR
   1           | 2013
               | 2014


   2           | 2011
               | 2012
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: actually i use sqlite

Comment: please provide sample data from the payments table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This result:

```
| CustomerId | Year |
|------------|------|
|          1 | 2013 |
|          1 | 2014 |
|          2 | 2011 |
|          2 | 2012 |
```

is produced by:

```
SELECT
        CustomerId
      , Year
FROM payments
GROUP BY
        CustomerId
      , Year
;
```

Comment: i want to see only one customer id on top,others must show empty

Comment: that's not the job of SQL, which will repeat that data deliberately. how will you use this, for example how would you sort it if you have nulls? how would you select from it if you have nulls?

Comment: I will export this data to excel sheet.And i have too many rows in my table.If i do this job from server side,i spend time,so i research to handle this on sql.is that impossible that i want ?

Comment: Just hide the unwanted data once it is in Excel, believe me you actually need the customerid on every row (for example to do a pivot table this would be essential). SQL is not a formatting tool.